# What can change a file created/modified date?

Tags: c#, windows, file

I'm using a file modified date as a base for file names in via C#. My question is what can make the modified date to change?
I actually thought the modified date was the created date first. But the created date is changing when I move the file from USB to harddrive. So I had to use the modified date which has the correct, untoched date.

As I thought when the file was moved the modified date was changed but its actually the created date that is changed in Windows 7 at least.

Is there any use case that may change the date of the file (except unpacking it from a zipped file) surprisingly? Like maybe from DVD to harddrive or something like that?

Best regards
Mr Rob

Comment: When you open the file with write access and save it back or when you just started to write the file.

Comment: you do realize that when "moving" files between file systems, a move is a copy+delete? create new file, delete old one. hence you get a new create date AND a new modified date. moving WITHIN a filesystem is simply updating a pointer somewhere to tell the OS/filesystem that the file is in a new location

Comment: [Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx). Literally, any other piece of code *may* choose to change timestamps on files.

Comment: @MarcB: usually, the creation date changes but the modification date does not, because CopyFile() copies the modification date from the original to the destination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### File properties with regards to the date and time stamps

- If you copy a file from C:\fat16 to C:\fat16\sub, it keeps the same modified date and time but it changes the created date and time to the current date and time.
- If you move a file from C:\fat16 to C:\fat16sub, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.
- If you copy a file from C:\fat16 to D:\NTFS, it keeps the same modified date and time but changes the created date and time to the current date and time.
- If you move a file from C:\fat16 to D:\NTFS, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.
- If you copy a file from D:\NTFS to D:\NTFS\SUB, it keeps the same modified date and time but changes the created date and time to the current date and time.
- If you move a file from D:\NTFS to D:\NTFS\SUB, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.
- In all examples, the modified date and time of a file does not change unless a property of the file has changed. The created date and time of the file changes depending on whether the file was copied or moved.

For more information see [KB299648](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299648).

Comment: last access stamp however changes on both move and copy

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the "original created date/time" from the non-copied file or is this information discarded when copying a file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the modification date would be changed when the file contents change.