# Not getting actual file created date after moving the file in another folder in c#

Tags: c#, file, date

i am trying to get the File Created date  Everything is working fine but if i am moving the file from one folder to another folder that it is loosing its actual date and returning  the current date. i know it works on the directory and file creation Date. But i need the actual created date.
Thanks for the help in Advance.

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(file);
```

Comment: Does the file name is exactly similar to another deleted file in the same folder/path ?
Do you override another file when moving it ?

Comment: Try Modification Date.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894749/what-can-change-a-file-created-modified-date

Comment: @kaj yeah i am just moving file without renaming it

Comment: @prathamthakur Look at my answer to understand why I'm asking.

Comment: @jdweng I need actual created date and it will give the last modification date

Comment: Why is the original create date so important.  Don't you really want the last time it was modified?

Comment: @kaj oh sorry i just give you incomplete answer. there is no any file with same name which is deleted and not overriding any file.The folder is totally empty.

Comment: @jdweng Actually i have large no of files and i have to move some files on the basis of their thats why actual date is so important

Comment: @JQSOFT it's helpful. But in my case the file processing through multiple folders and it is loosing its actual created date

Comment: I think the posted answer should resolve your problem. Before moving a file get it's [File.GetCreationTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtimeutc?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_GetCreationTimeUtc_System_String_) and [File.SetCreationTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setcreationtimeutc?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_SetCreationTimeUtc_System_String_System_DateTime_) after that.

Comment: @JQSOFT when i get the file so it has already lost its original created date so i can't set the date as i have no idea about actual date neither i have permissions to do this

Answer (score 1):

If the file is overriding another file in the same folder, or it's name is exactly similar to another deleted file, so it'll take the other file creation date because of [file system tunnelling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923)

An easy workaround is to read the creation date of the file before move it, then after moving it, set the creation date that you got using:

```
File.SetCreationTime
```

[File.SetCreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This is nice thought but when i am not able to make changes in file due to some security reasons.

Comment: I don't know what is the reason exactly why it's changed on Move and not **Copy**

Comment: No issue .Thanks for the Help !!

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to get file time informations, when any file was created, last modified or accessed. To get file datetime info you can use either static methods of File class or instance methods of FileInfo class.
https://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/